# How Comprehensive is DISCOSweb?

Tags: debris

The DISCOSweb API seems to contain a list of all launches as well as significant amounts of tracked debris.

I'm just wondering how conclusive I can consider this dataset to be? Does it contain all tracked debris or just a subset?